# классы в пайтон

Tags: python, ооп, класс

Код выдает ошибку:

> ```
> File "main.py", line 4
>    def__init__(self):
>                     ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Текст скопирован с учебника. В чем может быть проблема?

```
import random

class Coin:
    def__init__(self):
        self.sideup = 'Орел'
    def toss(self):
        if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            self.sideup = 'Орел' 
        else:
            self.sideup = 'Решка'
    def get_sideup(self):
        return self.sideup
def main():
    my_coin = Coin()
    print('Эта сторона обращена вверх: ', my_coin.get_sideup())
    print('Подбрасываю монету.....')
    my_coin.toss()
    print('Эта сторона обращена вверх', my_coin.get_sideup())
main()
```

Comment: def __init__(self):

Comment: Можно в функций toss условие записать в одну строчку  self.sideup = 'Решка' if random.randint(0, 1) else 'Орел'

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

class Coin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sideup = 'Орел'
    def toss(self):
        if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            self.sideup = 'Орел' 
        else:
            self.sideup = 'Решка'
    def get_sideup(self):
        return self.sideup
def main():
    my_coin = Coin()
    print('Эта сторона обращена вверх: ', my_coin.get_sideup())
    print('Подбрасываю монету.....')
    my_coin.toss()
    print('Эта сторона обращена вверх', my_coin.get_sideup())
main()
```

Ты забыл пробел в 4 строке.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!